# SQLALCHEMY not utilising the entire connection pool

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, gunicorn, clickhouse

I am new to flask and sqlalchemy and trying to wrtie an API that can support throughputs of 400 requests/sec.

I am using sqlalchemy to connect to a clickhouse database.

my sqlalchemy settings are:

```
 SQLALCHEMY_BINDS_OPTIONS = {
        'db': {
            'pool_size': 150,
            'echo_pool': True,
            'max_overflow': 15,
            'pool_pre_ping': True,

        }
    }
```

I am printing the no connections established by sqlalchemy and recycled by doing this in logger.py:

```
class ConnectionPoolHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.open_connections = 0
        self.recycled_connections = 0

    def emit(self, record):
        if record.getMessage().startswith('Created new connection'):
            self.open_connections += 1
            print(
                f'{record.getMessage()} (Open connections: {self.open_connections}, Recycled connections: {self.recycled_connections})'
            )
        elif record.getMessage().startswith('Recycling connection'):
            self.recycled_connections += 1

# Set up SQLAlchemy connection pool logging
sqlalchemy_connection_pool_logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.pool')
sqlalchemy_connection_pool_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = ConnectionPoolHandler()  # Create an instance of ConnectionPoolHandler
sqlalchemy_connection_pool_logger.addHandler(handler)
sqlalchemy_connection_pool_logger.propagate = False  # disable propagation of messages to parent logger
```

I am using gunicorn as a proxy to handle requests to the flask API.
I am using a threadpooolexecutor to parallelise query executions.

```
def get_threaded_mock_response():
    try:
        with app.app_context():
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
                get_response_1_future = executor.submit(g1)
                get_response_2_future = executor.submit(g2)
                get_response_3_future = executor.submit(g3)
                get_response_4_future = executor.submit(g4)

        response_1 = get_response_1_future.result()

        response_2 = get_response_2_future.result()

        response_3 = get_response_3_future.result()

        response_4 = get_response_4_future.result()

        response = []
        response.append(response_1)
        response.append(response_2)
        response.append(response_3)
        response.append(response_4)
        response_data = jsonify(response)
        return response_data
    except Exception as e:
        log_app(e, logging.ERROR)
        return {"message": internal_error_message}, 500


def g1():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    return {
        "g1": 1
    }


def g2():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    return {
        "g2": 2
    }


def g3():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    return {
        "g3": 3
    }


def g4():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    return {
        "g4": 4
    }
```

I have functions that run queries parallely as well just as above.
assuming each query takes 250ms to execute.

I am expecting that
1 connection can handle 4 queries per second.
therefore 1 request per connection /second
which means given my max allowed pool size of 150

sqlalchemy should support 150 req/second.

but my observations are:

1. 1 worker and 1 thread - 4 connections are open by sqlalchemy always and no connections are recycled.
2. 16 workers and 64 threads  - 15 connections are open and non recycled.
3. the ch db metrics show max 40 connection being open at peaks.

I have independently tested both flask API and CH:

1. by hitting the above mock endpoint and getting 400req/sec throughput.
2. my CH db is configured to have 500 parallel requests.
3. when I do a test of 200 requests, the cpu utilised by CH is not more than 25%.

what I can do here to improve throughput.
considering my flask app is not using even 25% of allocated resources and neither is CH db.

Comment: What do you mean no connections are recycled?  Do you mean kept open and used again OR do you mean closed?

Comment: Also, how many cpus/cores does the test system have available ?

Comment: Also if a connection could process 4 queries a second and you wanted 150 queries a second then you would only need a pool size of 150 / 4 = 37.5.  Each of the connections would remain open for that second and process 4 queries each.

Comment: Recycled - I mean closed. Connections not being recycled means all open connections are still active and can be still used. I am using a 4 cpu machine. Considering 37.5 connections as well. I can see only 4 connections being opened.

Comment: "I am using gunicorn as a proxy to handle requests to the flask API. "  Can you clarify if you are running flask with gunicorn and if not and you are truly running a proxy then what wsgi server you are running the flask api with ?

Comment: I am running flask with gunicorn. Will re word